# Why is there such a disconnect between server side models,validations, etc and client side?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, client-side, server-side

I've been bouncing back and forth lately on different client-side JavaScript libraries/frameworks.  I like Backbone.  Not a fan of ExtJs.  Etc.

Anyway, they all seem to have one giant problem in that I have to define validation logic in both the server side (`Rails 3`) and client side.  Plus, I have to do the same with my model definitions (`AR Objects` and `JS Objects').  Then I have to define the business rules in both places too.

Seems like I'm always developing two concurrent applications.

I know this is a subjective question, but for us small one-man teams who can't afford dedicated JS guys and dedicated Ruby guys, what are my solutions?

I'm racking my brain and maybe I'm missing something but I can't find a single solution to this problem.

I thought about writing a Ruby gem that would generate local JS objects.  So at least my business objects would be the same.  But this sounds scary.  Especially since I may not want all attributes client-side.

What are your thoughts on this problem?  Do I just have to live with it?

Comment: Have a page that can determine whether something is valid or not depending on specificied data type and make an AJAX call to that page? That's what I would do, anyway.

Comment: @user1090190 this is a solution but you don't have the "instant" feedback which is provided when your validation rules are implemented right on your client code

Comment: @pomeh Your server has to take an extra hit but the end user still avoids a hard postback (which is the point of JS side validation, is it not?)

Comment: Yes and no. With this technique, you can't do partial validation (like validate *one* field only), or you could do it but this would means make X hit server for X fields, which is not the same as only 1 hit which could be acceptable. Also, if we talk about MVC on the client, it way faster to "query" a local Model than request the server to get the models objects and so on. As I did, I think AJAX could be a solution to avoid code duplication (server & client), but it doesn't have the "instant" feedback or it has with a lot of inconvenient.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it takes a user longer to type in their input than the AJAX call is going to take. Yeah, it isn't instant, but is the only real solution to rewriting the same logic in two languages (that has been suggested, anyway).

Comment: Perhaps rephrase your question to state "How do I overcome the disconnect..." seeing that you're after a solution to it rather than an explanation of why the extra effort is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's something you just have to live with.  If you think about the nature of the problem, and WHY we do both client and server data validation, you can come to the conclusion that there isn't currently a way around it without degrading the user experience or putting your application at risk.

Think about it like you are sending a shipment of goods across the country on a train.  At the source location, somebody checks the logs to make sure that everything in the order has been included on the train, and that none of the goods are damaged.  At the destination, another person checks that they've received everything they ordered in the shipment, and that nothing is damaged.

What happens if you skip one of those validation steps? You run the risk of sending an incomplete shipment without your "server" side validation.  Without validating the incoming shipment on the other end, if someone were to hijack the train and swap out a bunch of counterfeit goods, you wouldn't find out about it until the goods had been sold and the cops were at your door.

The time (and expense) it takes the train to get from one location to the other creates an incentive to validate both incoming and outgoing goods, simply because an error on either end requires another train to be sent.

Admittedly, this metaphor is kind of a stretch, but hopefully you get the picture.  We **need** validation on both ends.

Comment: While I agree with you, I think this is not exactly his question. It was more about "how to avoid doing the work twice"

Comment: @pomeh You're right, and I knew that, but I feel like a lot of people are frustrated by this problem and might not understand why it's necessary, so I took a stab at clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

This is because those are two "closed domains" which don't overlap themselves. A code on the server, a code on the client. You can't do PHP/Ruby/Python/OtherServerLanguage on the client, and you can't do Javascript on the server. Oh wait ! [There you can !](http://nodejs.org/)

I see three kinds of solutions:

- build a tool that generate rules for one of the two domains, example: get/parse your ruby code, and generate the Javascript related to it (models, validation rules etc),
- use a tool to convert one server side language to Javascript, there are TONS out there https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS
- use the same language for both domains, with something similar to node.js http://nodejs.org/ which bring Javascript on the server. That way, you can write your code once and run it server-side and client-side, so your code base could be reused :) This pattern only ask you to decouple all you code in small independent modules